# backbone.js cannot extend router

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, requirejs

Well, this is annoying...

I'm using backbone.js with require.js. I'm trying to define router in a separate file and then instantiate it on the page. I tried a couple of ways and only one seems to work, this :

index.phtml

```
require(['/js/accounting/invoice/index/router.js'], function(Router) {
    window.R = new (Backbone.Router.extend(Router));
});
```

router.js returns an object thats used to extend Router. This is the only syntax that seems to work for me. writing it like :

```
window.R = Backbone.Router.extend(Router);
```

somehow produces a variable R which is an empty function.

My question is why the first approach works and any other doesn't ? I love that fact that it works and yet I'm frustrated that I have no idea why. It also seems wildly different from what I've seen in the tutorials.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's expected behaviour.

Let's check out what are you doing with your first approach and what is done with the second one.

Backbone usually has a special `.extend` method to every class that can enhance the class prototype, before you initialize it.

It looks like this :

```
var Model = Backbone.Model.extend({});
var myModel = new Model({ name: 'myModel' });
```

What `.extend` method returns is the class itself, with the extended properties that you have provided. It basically takes `.prototype` and adds to it the specified as argument object. But it **doesn't initialize the class**. You initialize the class with `new ClassName();`.

So if you see your first approach :

```
window.R = new (Backbone.Router.extend(Router));
```

It actually executes ( is equal to ) :

```
var a = Backbone.Router.extend(Router); // Your second approach ends here
window.R = new a();
```

With your second approach you actually assign to `window.R` with the **non-initalized** class object and actually non-initialized class object is just a normal `function`.

Comment: So I guess it is bad to skip learning the fundamentals after all. Thanks :)